# Is there any alternative to LocalBroadcastManager, for triggering Activity function from a Worker?

Tags: java, android

I created some `Worker` classes. I would like to run a function on the Activity, after each worker was finished.

My plan was to use `LocalBroadcastManager`, trigger an event from the Worker, and receive the event in the Activity. Unfortunately `LocalBroadcastManager` is deprecated.

I cannot use `LiveData`, because the worker may run in the background, as a periodic work, and I can not share the `LiveData` instance between workers and activities. The works that I would like to observe are tagged, but if I use `getWorkInfosByTagLiveData`, I get a `List<WorkInfo>` after each update, and I have no idea, which item in that list was updated.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have much experience in this field but I have found a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61484995/localbroadcastmanager-has-been-deprecated-what-i-should-use-instead-in-its-plac) that was already answered. In the answer, they show an alternative to `LocalBroadcastManager` that might help.

`LocalBroadcastManager` is an Event bus, these still have the same problems that lead to `LocalBroadcastManager` being depreciated.

I'm sorry if I have misunderstood.

Comment: It suggests `LiveData`, but as I mentioned, I don't know, how to share the `LiveData` instance between workers and activities